# Convert office document to pdf and display it on the browser

Tags: jsf, pdf, liferay, converters, fileinputstream

***Please see the update question below (not the top one).***

I tried to open any document type (especially PDF) on Liferay using this function. But I always get message `Awt Desktop is not supported!` as stated on the function. How can I enable the Awt Desktop? I tried searching over the internet and found nothing. Anyone help, pls? Thanks.

```
public void viewFileByAwt(String file) {
    try {
        File File = new File(getPath(file));
        if (File.exists()) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(File);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
            }
        } else {
            //File is not exists
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-java/

---

## UPDATE

As you see the code below, both mode (`1` for download and `2` for preview) is working pretty well, but unfortunately the second mode (preview mode) is works only for PDF.

Now what I want to do is, while user clicking the `preview` button, files another than PDF (limited only for extension: **DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, ODT, ODS**) must be converted to PDF first, and then display it on the browser with the same way as below code explained. Is it possible to do that? If it's too hard to have all of the converter on a function, then on a separated function each extension would be fine.

```
public StreamedContent getFileSelected(final StreamedContent doc, int mode) throws Exception {
    //Mode: 1-download, 2-preview
    try {
        File localfile = new File(getPath(doc.getName()));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(localfile);
        if (mode == 2 && !(doc.getName().substring(doc.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1)).matches("pdf")) {
            localfile = DocumentConversionUtil.convert(doc.getName(), fis, doc.getName().substring(doc.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1), "pdf");
            fis = new FileInputStream(localfile.getPath());
        }

        if (localfile.exists()) {
            try {
                PortletResponse portletResponse = (PortletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
                HttpServletResponse res = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(portletResponse);
                if (mode == 1)      res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + doc.getName() + "\"");
                else if (mode == 2) res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + doc.getName() + "\"");
                res.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                res.setContentType(getMimeType(localfile.getName().substring(localfile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1)));
                res.flushBuffer();
                OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    buffer = new byte[4096];
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (fis != null)
                        fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: As to your initial question: you're making a huge conceptual mistake. Java code runs in webserver, not in webbrowser. The only circumstance where this will "look like" to work is when both the webserver and webbrowser happens to run at physically the same machine, like as when you're developing. But this does definitely not happen in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first install openoffice on your machine
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/openoffice

After configuring openoffice with liferay, you can use DocumentConversionUtil class from liferay to convert documents.

```
DocumentConversionUtil.convert(String id, InputStream is, String sourceExtension,String targetExtension)
```

Above code will return inputstream. After this conversion you can show pdf in your browser
Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 2):

Liferay is a portal server; its user interface runs in a browser.  AWT is the Java 1.0 basis for desktop UIs.

I don't think AWT is the way to display it.

Why can't you open the file and stream the bytes to the portlet using the application/pdf MIME type?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have update my question above, please take a look. Is that possible to convert any type of documents (instead of pdf) into pdf (before showing it on the browser)?

Comment: Anything you can convert into PDF can be rendered that way, but the conversion may not be trivial.  If you can't convert, you have to think of something else.